# Location Services not working on Mac Book

Tags: macos, wifi, big-sur, geolocation, gps

I am using a Mac Book Pro 13" 2020 Model with Mac OS Big Sur 11.1 Running. Recently i have noticed that no any location services based apps such as Find My, Siri, Maps can not be able to locate me. All the setting are correct and have tried resetting the NVRAM too. Had a conversation with apple and they requested my to do Mac OS Clean Installation. So before i do the Clean Installation i have tried with another WiFi Router and all my location services working fine.
And Location services working for my router too if the new wifi router is nearby and switched on.

So where is the actual problem ? I thought to replace my router but is also working fine if the new router is just nearby and turned on. I no need to connect it though.

Comment: Have you tried the solution found in a similar, and older, [question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/155326/88313)?

Comment: @fsb yes. but did not worked for me

Comment: same bug, have you ever find a way to solve it?